# couchdb good for this case?

Tags: couchdb, document-oriented-db, document-oriented

I am looking to create a cv bank which when i think about it in terms of storing the data in a relational database the complexity is pretty apparent. Would couchdb make better sense in this case?

example of things i would be storing

each a 1 to many relationships with user
education, qualifications, employment, awards, languages, skills, licenses, assosations

Answer (score 1):

CouchDB is a good option, but remember to also use Lucene, which you can feed off CouchDB using couchdb-lucene (http://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene) as more probably than not you'll want to search that CV bank.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

However without knowing your project in detail, you should consider storing everything about an individual person inside one document. You will find it much easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

kindly, i thought CouchDB is perfect for your project, as CV and Resume in its abstract views is documents.